# How to properly append Ajax result to existing ul, li using jquery

Tags: jquery

I've checked all the previous answers to the recommended questions and I can't figure out what i'm doing wrong.

Currently I'm making an ajax call with this code:

```
  $(".pricingCalculator").ready(function(){

   $('#size li').on('click', function(){

    if($(this).text() != '')
    {
      var productId =  $(this).attr("value");

      // here we'll make ajax call to post details of dropdown and get new data
     $.ajax({
      url:"{{ url('product_details/fetch/productId') }}".replace("productId", productId),
      dataType: "json",
      success:function(result)
      {
      // clear the drop downs so no data will be there
      $("ul[data-dependent='quantity']").empty();

      // add quantity drop down based on selected size
      $.each(result.productQuanties, function(i, item) {
      $("ul[data-dependent='quantity']").append("<li value=" + item.quantity_name + "><span>" + item.quantity_name + "</span></li>");
      })

      // add stock options based on selected size
      $.each(result.productPaperStock, function(i, item) {
      $("ul[data-dependent='stock']").append("<li value=" + item.name + "><span>" + item.name + "</span></li>");
      })
      //$("ul[data-dependent='quantity']").html(productQuantity);
      }
     })
    }
   });
```

My ajax calls returns the proper data and it creates the li and values which is visible in the html.  Here is an example of the html block before the li gets inserted.

```
  <div class="block-options col-md-4 col-sm-5">
    <div class="options-col">
      <span class="cur-option-w">
        <span class="cur-option-val">Quantity</span>
        <i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i>
      </span>
      <ul class="d-none po-list" name="quantity" id="quantity" data-dependent="quantity">
        <li><span>Please select size</span></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

After the ajax data is inserted I get my list like so.
[image]

The problem is I can't select that data.  By select I mean simply click it and it be highlighted.  I read up on binding but I couldn't figure out what I'm doing wrong.  There's a few questions here that cover how to append jquery ajax and also about binding the elements.

Comment: when you load your page for the first time, is it working. if so, compare what is working to what you're injecting or appending in your script to see any missing style to `li` elem. plz share your complete html code to better understand ur issue and be able to address it

Comment: Not sure what CSS framework you're using, but there appears to be a javascript element involved that is not aware of the change you made to the UL.

Comment: @msoliman yes I made sure li matches exactly.

Comment: You obviously instantiate a plugin that uses `ul` and `li` structure and make it look like a `select`. You have to "destroy" that instance and re-instantiate so it will take the new values in account.

Comment: @Louys Patrice Bessette that's exactly what it is.  Thank you